# How to control parallel processes with condition

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to control my processes while I not found working url.

But I have `NameError: name 'status' is not defined` due to threads not waiting to declare a variable

```
import requests
from multiprocessing import Process


def first_function(i):
    global status
    status = False
    try:
        response = requests.get(f'https://ru.hexlet.io/{i}')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            status = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def second_function():
    for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,'courses',8,9,10]:
        Process(target=first_function, args=(i, )).start()
        print(i)
        if status:
            print('working', i)
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    second_function()
```

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing processes and threads. Processes run in different memory-spaces and don't share global variables.

Comment: So is there any way to control it in that case?

Comment: @middleStackoverflower check https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value to store a shared boolean value

Comment: I am not sure because the example code doesn't make much sense. If it's running 10 different processes concurrently, what `status` is it checking?

Comment: @martineau, example code is example, try to think that this loop will work with 10k-20k length array

Comment: The sheer number of processes isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) to limit the number of processes that are run concurrently (since you have indicated there might be a very large number of them).

If you use its [`apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) method to "submit" tasks to it, you can use the optional `callback` argumet to specify a function that will get called whenever one of the subprocesses finishes. This provides a way to terminate further processing by other processes submitted to the `pool`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests


def worker(i):
    try:
        response = requests.get(f'https://ru.hexlet.io/{i}')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return i
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f'{i!r} caused {exc}')
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def notify(i):
        """Called when a Pool worker process finishes execution."""
        if i is not None:
            print(f'{i!r} worked')
            pool.terminate()  # Stops worker processes immediately.

    pool = mp.Pool()

    for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,'courses',8,9,10]:
        pool.apply_async(worker, (i,), callback=notify)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('fini')
```

Output:

```
'courses' worked
fini
```